# using Dispatcher.Invoke() and still get the "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" exception

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I have this snippet of code:

```
        plane.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            plane.Geometry = mesh;
        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

which i put inside of an event handler method i have in my window class. the caller of this handler is a thread that handles TCP data.
plane is a GeometryModel3D object that is initialized in the XAML.
that should run smoothly from a non UI thread, right?
but still i get this annoying exception that this is not the UI thread.
Also, tried - this.Dispatcher.Invoke - by "this.Dispatcher" i mean Window.Dispatcher.

any ideas this doesn't work?

Comment: Try `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` and (optionally) `plane.Geometry = mesh.Clone();`

Comment: Tried it, still the same exception.

Comment: Is the error coming on `plane` or `mesh` object?

Comment: I think that it's on the mesh.

Comment: Thanks, I did move the declaration for mesh inside the Invoke block and it solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to declare the mesh object inside the invocation block.